# Which of the following statements about linear system equations are correct?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

> **Question:** Which of the following statements about linear system equations are correct?
>
> **Statements:**
>
> 1. A non-homogeneous system equations $Ax = b$ with $A$ of size $6\times7$ can have a unique solution for a particular right-hand side $b$.
> 2. A homogeneous system equations $Ax = 0$ with the size $6\times6$ matrix $A$ can have the amount of all solutions spanned by two vectors.
> 3. A non-homogeneous system equations $Ax = b$ with the size $A$ of size $7\times6$ can have a unique solution for a particular right-hand side $b$.
> 4. A system equations $Ax = 0$ with the size $A$ of size $10\times12$ of can have the amount of all solutions consisting of multiples of a vector.
> 5. A system equations $Ax = 0$ with the size $7\times10$ matrix $A$ can have the amount of all solutions spanned by two vectors.

**My answer:**

It stands still in my head and I don't know where to start from  to be able control of which statement that is true or false. Please help me!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. We usually don't provide full answers to homework-type questions. I suggest that you provide some thought about your progress so far and the specific points you got stuck. We can give a better feedback this way if we know what exactly is your problem.

Comment: aha okey i will try to give a better answer

Answer (score 0):

We can look at it one at a time. I won't just give the answer because it is clearly a homework question but we can work through this together. The first thing you should ask yourself is: What is this question really asking about?

Answer 1 shows an equation `Ax=b`and asks if A is a 6x7 matrix, can we solve for x. Well, what does a 6x7 matrix mean? How many rows and how many columns? What do the columns mean? Notice there is a mismatch between rows and columns, what does that mean?

Answer 2 is like answer one but b = 0, which means what? What does it mean to have a system spanned by vectors?

Answer 3 is like answer 1 but what is different?

Answer 4 is similar to answers 1 and 3 but what is it asking about this time with "multiples of a vector"?

Answer 5 is like answer 2 but what is different?

Comment: 1 is a m*n matrix but says that is has a unique solution but 3 is also a m*n matrix but says that is can have the amount of all solutions spanned by two vectors. 2 is a n*n matrix and can have the amount of all solutions spanned by two vectors and 5 is a m*n and can have the amount of all solutions spanned by two vectors.

Comment: So can answer 1 be true? Can a mn matrix where m < n have a unique solution?

Comment: I guess that when it is a m*n matrix it can have the amount of all solutions spanned by two vectors. When it is a n*n it can only have one solution. That gives us that the only ones that are true are 4 and 5. Am I wrong?

Comment: Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Please answer me

Comment: I did not fully understand your reasoning there. Why did you rule out 1, 2, and 3? What is answer 4 asking? A matrix of size 10x12 means 10 rows and 12 columns, which means how many variables and how many equations? What does it mean to be "multiples of a vector"?

Comment: What does spanning a system with only two vectors indicate? How many vectors do you need to span a 3-D system? How many dimensions are in a 7x10 matrix?

Comment: The ones that have more variable then equations can have the amount of all solutions spanned by two vectors. The ones that are n*n can have one solution

Comment: Ok and it seems to me that we have ruled out answer 3 too soon. With these discussions, you can make a new post (delete this one) with the question along with these discussions to get further confirmation from others